# I am getting the correct end value, but with the wrong numbers

Tags: java, if-statement, rectangles

I am working on a program that calculates the maximum area that can be attained for a fenced-in area, when you have only 100 yards of fencing.  One of the four sides is defined by an arbitrarily long fence that already exists.  The correct answer (the maximum area) is 1250 yards, which I am getting when I rum the program.  However, I am also required to print out the width and length dimensions to go along with that value, and I am getting *very* strange numbers for those values (which are supposed to be 25 and 50).  Can anybody explain why this is happening, and how might I fix it?

```
public class Prog215c{
    public static void main (String[] args){
   //Initalizing the final dimension variables
   double fin_l = 0;
   double fin_w = 0;

   //Initalizing the area variables
   double area = 0;
   double prev_area = 0;
   double max_area = 0;

   //Trying all l values
   for (double l = 100; l > 0; l--){

       //Calculating the w value from the l value
       double w = (100-l) / 2;

       //Calculating the area
       area = l * w;

       if (area >= prev_area){
               prev_area = area;

                }

              else{
                  max_area = prev_area;
                  fin_l = l;
                  fin_w = w;

                }   
    }
   //Outprinting the results 
   System.out.println("With 100 yards of fencing material:");
   System.out.println("A rectangle " + fin_w + " X " + fin_l + " yards produces the maximum area of " +
   max_area + " square yards.");


 }
    }


     /*Sample Output
    With 100 yards of fencing material:
    A rectangle 49.5 X 1.0 yards produces the maximum area of 1250.0          square yards.


     */
```

Ignore the space after the 1250.0 (formatting on stack overflow)

Comment: what is `and I am getting very strange numbers for those values`

Comment: @Eli Sadoff: Do you have any ideas of how to fix the problem?

Comment: @Scary Wombat: I included the output at the bottom (you might have to scroll a bit)

Comment: @Flightless_bird I haven't really looked at the problem. I just made the formatting a little more readable.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes more sense to set the variables as

```
 if (area >= prev_area){
    prev_area = area;
    fin_l = l;
    fin_w = w;
 }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks, Scary Wombat!

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
if (area >= prev_area){
           prev_area = area;
}

else{
      max_area = prev_area;
      fin_l = l;
      fin_w = w;

            }
```

by this:

```
if (area >= prev_area){
           prev_area = area;
           fin_l = l;
           fin_w = w;
            }

          else{
              max_area = prev_area;


            }
```

Comment: oups looks like I'm too late.